How to create a module for gitlab_user_runner and use the token every time a new runner is created in root
If i create multiple runners with below module - project_runner. Then can i use the output token for each runner once it is created in the subsequent lambda as env variable ?
module.project_runner.runner_token -- will  output the particular runner token every time it is created or it will take the first runner's token always?
main.tf
module "project_runner" {
  source             = "./modules/gitlab_user_runner"
  runner_type        = project_type 
}

module "test-lambda" {
function_name      = "test-lambda"
  environment_variables = {
    GITLAB_TOKEN     = module.project_runner.runner_token
    CONFIG_TOML      = module.project_runner.config_toml
  }
}


I'm not sure I understood the question, but if you were to use the module with count or for_each, you could access the particular output of the module based on the index (for count) or the key (with for_each). However, in that case, you probably also want to have multiple Lambda functions. If that is not the case, then you need to know exactly which output you need to use to be able to reference it properly.

Thank you for the response. Your understanding is correct. I want to create multiple runners and then use their output tokens in one lambda via SQS queue . How can i achieve this.

So many tokens to be used by only one Lambda function?

If you are creating multiple modules then you either need to give them different names or use a for_each.
For example, using different names.
module "project_runner_1" {
  source             = "./modules/gitlab_user_runner"
  runner_type        = var.project_type 
}

module "test-lambda" {
function_name      = "test-lambda"
  environment_variables = {
    GITLAB_TOKEN     = module.project_runner_1.runner_token
    CONFIG_TOML      = module.project_runner_1.config_toml
  }
}

module "project_runner_2" {
  source             = "./modules/gitlab_user_runner"
  runner_type        = var.project_type 
}

module "test-lambda" {
function_name      = "test-lambda"
  environment_variables = {
    GITLAB_TOKEN     = module.project_runner_2.runner_token
    CONFIG_TOML      = module.project_runner_2.config_toml
  }
}

The lambda environment variables can only reference one instance of the project runner module. I would not recommend doing it this way as each new instance requires you to copy and paste. Instead it would be better to use for_each or count to create multiple instances of the same module.
module "project_runner" {
  count              = 2
  source             = "./modules/gitlab_user_runner"
  runner_type        = var.project_type 
}

module "test-lambda" {
  count                 = 2
  function_name         = "test-lambda"
  environment_variables = {
    GITLAB_TOKEN     = module.project_runner[count.index].runner_token
    CONFIG_TOML      = module.project_runner[count.index].config_toml
  }
}

In the above example module.project_runner is now a list with two items in it, each contains the output from the respective instances of the project_runner module.
[
  {
    runner_token = "foo"
    config_toml = ...
  },
  {
    runner_token = "bar"
    config_toml = ...
  }
]

When creating 2 instances of the test lambda the project runner output with the same index can be referenced using module.project_runner[count.index].
The first test lambda instance will be passed runner_token = "foo", and the second instance will be passed runner_token = "bar".
Using for_each allows for configuration to be supplied to each instance.
locals {
  runner_config = {
    runner1 = {
      type = "project"
    }
    runner2 = {
      type = "group"
    }
  }
}

module "project_runner" {
  for_each           = local.runner_config
  source             = "./modules/gitlab_user_runner"
  runner_type        = each.value.type
  name               = each.key
}

module "test-lambda" {
  for_each              = local.runner_config
  function_name         = "test-lambda-${each.key}"
  environment_variables = {
    GITLAB_TOKEN     = module.project_runner[each.key].runner_token
    CONFIG_TOML      = module.project_runner[each.key].config_toml
  }
}



I plan to do this with - for_each or count to create multiple instances , but i am struggling with input variable type here. runner.tf
runner_configs = [
Runner1 {
name    = "runner1"
},

Runner2 {
name    = "runner2"
.......................... }
]

@2024KD I have updated my answer with an example using for_each

Is there a way i can pass the runner_configs values from a seperate runner.tf file ?

Terraform will append all *.tf files in the working directory together. You can move the runner_config local into any other *.tf file in the same folder and the local.runner_config reference will still work.

Thank you. I will try and update.

So i created a runner.tf file with below : locals {
runner_config = {
r1 = {
runner_type        = "project_type"
project_id         = "123"
runner_name        = "runner-test"
runner_description = "for testing"
}
}
}.

module "gitlab_project_runner" {
for_each           = local.runner_config
source             = "./modules/gitlab_user_runner"
runner_type        = each.value.runner_type # (required)
project_id         = each.value.runner_type == "project_type" ? each.value.project_id : null
runner_name        = each.value.runner_name
runner_description = each.value.runner_description
runner_locked      = each.value.runner_locked
}.

Then i am getting below error   Error: Unsupported attribute
on main.tf line 30, in module "gitlab_project_runner":
30:   runner_locked      = each.value.runner_locked   # (optional) default = true
This object does not have an attribute named "runner_locked".
